# Prove $a ≤ x ≤ b ⇒ x ≤ a +b ∀a,b ∊ R^+$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

It seems too obvious to be proved algebraically.
What i thought was:

We know that the sum of two positive numbers is a positive number so:

$a + b > b$ and $a + b > a$

Using the hypotesis of $a > x$ and $b > x$ then

$a + b > b > x$ and $a + b > a > x$

Is it correct? If you know, please tell me another way to prove it.

Comment: If $a > 0$, it is enough to note that $a + b > b$

Comment: You don't have the hypothesis $a>x$ (in fact you have the hypothesis $\neg (a>x)$) but essentially everything except the reasoning behind $a+b>b\ge x$ is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are on the right track, but you made one error in the final line with the $a + b > a > x$. I would solve this as:

$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $b<a+b$ and $a<a+b$ (definition of addition between two positive numbers)

Given $x, a, b$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$ and $b<a+b$ then we can conclude through the transitive property $a \leq x < b$ or

$$x<a+b \ \ \  \text{and} \ \ \ x \geq a$$

The only item I can't seem to prove is that $x \leq a+b$. I would say by the above proof, $x$ is strictly less than $a+b$.